# Changing IP in C++ by using addIPAdress()

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Like in the title - I've been working on code in **C++** that changes my IP address. The program **works** "alright" and shows it added new IP, however the old IP stay the same and **doesn't change**.

So what I have to fix in my code to get rid off of the problem

If entire script is wrong I would really appreciate an example of program which would work.

The code:

```
  #ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #endif

    #include <windows.h>
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iphlpapi.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE pIPAddrTable;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal;

    UINT IPAddress;
    UINT IPMask;

    ULONG NTEContext = 0;
    ULONG NTEInstance = 0;

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

    pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE *)malloc(sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE));

    if (GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE *)malloc(dwSize);
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\tAddress: %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwAddr);
        printf("\tMask:    %ld\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwMask);
    }
    else {
        printf("Call to GetIpAddrTable failed.\n");
    }

    IPAddress = inet_addr("192.168.0.2");
    IPMask = inet_addr("255.255.255.0");

    if ((dwRetVal = AddIPAddress(IPAddress,
        IPMask,
        pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwIndex,
        &NTEContext, &NTEInstance)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\tIP address added.\n");
    }

    else {
        printf("Error adding IP address.\n");

        if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwRetVal, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),       // Default language
            (LPTSTR)& lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL)) {
            printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
        }
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    }

    system("c:\\windows\\system32\\ipconfig");

    system("pause");
}
```

*Footnote: Program was modified from an example from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365875(v=vs.85).aspx Though, it contains error which makes my VS to reach breakpoints caused by 'GlobalFree(pIPAddrTable);'*

---

*If anyone interested I'm inviting for a C++ [project](https://github.com/CubaQ/Nimpha-IP) on GitHub*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All is conformant with MSDN documentation. The page on [AddIpAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365801(v=vs.85).aspx) states:

> The AddIPAddress function is used to add a new IPv4 address entry on a local computer. The IPv4 address added by the AddIPAddress function is not persistent...

That means that calling this function will have no effect on pre-existing network addresses and just add a temporary new one.

If you want the change the static network address, you should try to use the [EnableStatic method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I know it is bad to provide raw links, but Microsoft API for network configuration is really too ugly for me to give a simple example.